# Does Vim have something like <C-w> in insert mode which deletes back a Word?

Tags: vim

In insert mode, Vim will delete back a `word` if you press `<C-w>` (control + w). Is there a similar command that deletes back a `Word`?

(Eg, would delete all of `http://www.example.com` instead of just the `com` part.)

If not, I'm thinking of mapping `<C-BS>` (control + backspace) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such built-in command, but the following should do the trick:

```
:inoremap <silent> <expr> <C-S-BS>
\   col('.') == 1 ?
\       '<C-w>' :
\       col('.') >= col('$') ?
\           '<C-o>:normal! Bd$<CR>' :
\           '<C-o>:normal! m"Bdg`"<CR>'
```

When at the beginning of the line it just executes the `<C-w>` command to join with the previous line. At the end of the line, it goes back on WORD and deletes the rest. Otherwise, it establishes a temporary mark `m"`, goes back one WORD `B`, and deletes that part of the text.

*Edit: Fixed for cursor at end of the line*

Comment: This is nice, but a little buggy. If my cursor is directly after `whatever` and I use it, I end up with `r` leftover. If my cursor is after `whatever ` (after the space), it deletes the whole word but leaves two spaces after the previous word.

Comment: This seems to work for me: `imap <C-BS> <C-o>vBd`. You seem to have more Vim-fu than I do. Do you see any downsides? If not, want to roll that into your solution?

Comment: Using visual mode; that's clever! Unfortunately, it only works with `:set selection=exclusive`, and it clobbers the visual selection, which a well-behaved mapping shouldn't do.

Comment: Ah, I didn't test for end of line; I've edited in a fix. Now it's even more ugly than your alternative, though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, you are on a file in insert mode with your cursor on a char somewhere on 'com' and you press `<c-w>` to delete `http://www.example.com` and stay in insert mode ?

`blabla ffd http://www.example.com fds fsdf dsfd`

this key map do the trick :
`imap <C-w> <ESC>lciW`

`<ESC>` -> go in normal

`l` -> goto right (because when press ESC it goes to left)

`ciW` -> replace all Word and go in insert mode

Comment: Does this go backwards?  Don't you need to use `B`?

Comment: In my example, my cursor is somewhere on `http://www.example.com` so, after setting this 'inoremap' it delete all `http://www.example.com` and stay in insert mode. But yes, if I was on the first space next to `http://www.example.com` it wouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

while in insert mode, `Ctrl+O` then `dB`